# Creating new folders in java with dynamic naming

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, directory

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\new\\"+count);
if (!file.exists()) {
    if (file.mkdir()) {
        System.out.println("Directory is created!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
    }
```

This is my current code for making a folder. As you can see, I am using count (an integer) as my folder name. I have initialized count to zero. Now, I need to increment the counter for new folder, for the dynamic naming of folders, as required for my project. What modification should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursive method , if Folder already exists this will create new folder using counter

```
int count;

public void createFolder() {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\new\\"" + count);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (file.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            count++;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
        count++;
        createFolder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A more elegant version(java 8+):

```
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("/home/path1/path2/path3"));
```

The Files.createDirectories creates a new directory; if the parent directories do not exist, they are created as well. The method does not thrown an exception if the directory already exist.